# Magic mouse smart zoom not available on trackpad

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad

Smart zoom on the magic mouse allows to zoom on an area of page with double tap of magic mouse.

Viewing the trackpad options this smart zoom does not appear available ? Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for **Smart Zoom**.

Unless you've changed it from the default, tapping with 2 fingers will zoom in and out. 
[image]

See [this Apple page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895) for more options and gestures on the trackpad.